# ssh laravel server pull repository showing error500?

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, composer-php, apache2

I'm trying to run a project. I have pull the repository through ssh. But there are errors while pulling. and when I try to access the webpage, it show errors:
The front page url shows :

```
example.com is currently unable to handle this request.
    HTTP ERROR 500
```

My linux server apache2 is running. But when i check the error on /etc/log/apache2 on error.log, it shows:

```
           [Mon Feb 28 00:00:14.453907 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 774] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
        [Mon Feb 28 00:00:14.453934 2022] [core:notice] [pid 774] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
        [Mon Feb 28 04:26:16.096546 2022] [php7:error] [pid 14891] [client ......:59882] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/admin/vendor/psr/log/src/LoggerInterface.php on line 30
        [Mon Feb 28 04:26:16.096593 2022] [php7:error] [pid 14891] [client ....:59882] PHP Fatal error:  Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0
        [Mon Feb 28 04:26:16.097333 2022] [php7:error] [pid 14891] [client .....:59882] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/admin/vendor/psr/log/src/LoggerInterface.php on line 30
        [Mon Feb 28 04:26:16.097351 2022] [php7:error] [pid 14891] [client .....:59882] PHP Fatal error:  Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0
 [Mon Feb 28 00:00:14.453934 2022] [core:notice] [pid 774] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
        [Mon Feb 28 04:26:16.096546 2022] [php7:error] [pid 14891] [client ......:59882] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/admin/vendor/psr/log/src/LoggerInterface.php on line 30<br>
        [Mon Feb 28 04:26:16.096593 2022] [php7:error] [pid 14891] [client ....:59882] PHP Fatal error:  Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0<br>
        [Mon Feb 28 04:26:16.097333 2022] [php7:error] [pid 14891] [client .....:59882] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/admin/vendor/psr/log/src/LoggerInterface.php on line 30
        [Mon Feb 28 04:26:16.097351 2022] [php7:error] [pid 14891] [client .....:59882] PHP Fatal error:  Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0
```

For Php parse error, I configure composer.json file with

```
 "config": {
            "platform": {
                "php": "7.4.27"
             }
       }
```

and run:
 `composer dump-autoload`, it still shows the same errors
i remove the vendor directory and composer.lock file and reinstall the dependencies by running `composer install`
still it shows the error
I have given full permission to public and storage folder
I'm stuck onto it and could't access the webpage.
Any advice, suggestion, solution will be highly appreciated.
Thanking in advance!!

Comment: is the php version in your server is same as your local (project required) ?

Comment: have you installed all the required php extentions in your server ?

Comment: I have php7.4 on server and php7.4.27 on my local environment. My other projects on laravel works fine on local environment.